# Create two new columns derived from original columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, that contains two columns that contain quarter values. I would like to create two more columns that are the equivalent "long dates".

**Data**

```
ID  Quarter Delivery    
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022 
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022 
B   Q1 2022 Q3 2022 
B   Q1 2022 Q3 2022
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Quarter Delivery    QuarterFull DeliveryFull    
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022     1/1/2022    07/1/2022   
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022     1/1/2022    07/1/2022   
B   Q4 2022 Q2 2023     10/1/2022   04/1/2023   
B   Q4 2022 Q2 2023     10/1/2022   04/1/2023   


Q1 is 01
Q2 is 04
Q3 is 07
Q4 is 10
```

**Doing**

My approach/logic is to create variables or a dictionary that holds or map to specific dates
(key/value pairs)

```
dict = {
  "Q1": "01",
  "Q2": "04",
  "Q3": "07"
  "Q4": "10"
}
```

Not exactly sure how to implement this as columns. I am still troubleshooting this. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B'], 'Quarter':['Q1 2020', 'Q2 2021']})

def convDate(date):
  q, year = date.split()
  q = int(q[1])
  return f'{q*3-2:02d}/1/{year}'

df['QuarterFull'] = df['Quarter'].map(convDate)
df.head()
```

Output

```
   ID   Quarter QuarterFull
0   A   Q1 2020 01/1/2020
1   B   Q2 2021 04/1/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your dictionary `d` mapping:

```
d = {"Q1": "01", "Q2": "04", "Q3": "07", "Q4": "10"}
>>> df["Quarter"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(f"{d[x[:2]]} {x[-4:]}", format="%m %Y"))
0   2022-01-01
1   2022-01-01
2   2022-10-01
3   2022-10-01
Name: Quarter, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This way, the data is of datetime format.

Answer (score 1):

Without intermediate dict:

```
quarter_to_full_date = \
    lambda q: (pd.to_datetime(q.str.split().str[::-1].map("-".join)) \
    + pd.DateOffset(months=3)).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

df["QuarterFull"] = quarter_to_full_date(df["Quarter"]
df["DeliveryFull"] = quarter_to_full_date(df["Delivery"]
```

```
>>> df
  ID  Quarter Delivery QuarterFull
0  A  Q1 2022  Q3 2022  04/01/2022
1  A  Q1 2022  Q3 2022  04/01/2022
2  B  Q4 2022  Q2 2023  01/01/2023
3  B  Q4 2022  Q2 2023  01/01/2023
```