# Using a loop to match values that contain a certain string in a dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I have two columns that contain certain values. If the values match a specific string, I would like to then place a certain value in a new column for multiple columns.

Data

```
ID  Quarter Delivery    
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022 
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022 
B   Q1 2022 Q3 2022 
B   Q1 2022 Q3 2022
```

Desired

```
ID  Quarter Delivery    QuarterFull DeliveryFull    
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022     1/1/2022    07/1/2022   
A   Q1 2022 Q3 2022     1/1/2022    07/1/2022   
B   Q4 2022 Q2 2023     10/1/2022   04/1/2023   
B   Q4 2022 Q2 2023     10/1/2022   04/1/2023   


Q1 = 01
Q2 = 04
Q3 = 07
Q4 = 10
```

Doing

```
for Quarter, item in df.iteritems():
    

 if df['Quarter'] == df['Q1 2022']:
        return df['1/1/2022']
    elif df['Quarter'] == df['Q4 2022']:
        return df['10/1/2022']
    elif df['Delivery'] == df['Q3 2022']:
        return df['07/01/2022']
    elif df['Delivery'] == df['Q2 2023']:
        return df['04/01/2023]
    else:
        return df['None']
```

I believe running a loop may be the best way to approach since I have a decent sized dataset of 100,000 rows.
I am not sure how to add these two new columns to the dataframe while using the loop.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: All these the all of conditions you have/need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create two new columns derived from original columns in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843351/create-two-new-columns-derived-from-original-columns-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, but I think a loop is the better solution

Comment: No @crayxt I will expand, looking for a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just manipulate Quarter/Delivery column to get the required result:

```
df['Quarter'] = df['Quarter'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2-\1', regex =True)
df['Delivery'] = df['Delivery'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2-\1', regex =True)
df['QuarterFull'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Quarter'], freq='Q').to_timestamp().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
df['DeliveryFull'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Delivery'], freq='Q').to_timestamp().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  ID  Quarter Delivery QuarterFull DeliveryFull
0  A  2022-Q1  2022-Q3  01-01-2022   07-01-2022
1  A  2022-Q1  2022-Q3  01-01-2022   07-01-2022
2  B  2022-Q4  2022-Q2  10-01-2022   04-01-2022
3  B  2022-Q4  2022-Q2  10-01-2022   04-01-2022
```

Comment: Ah, I see, so you are essentially just converting the quarters to a full long date?

Comment: yup exactly!! @Lynn

Comment: This is exactly what I would like, let me test it. Thank you